# Downloading Steam games on different family laptops

Tags: steam

I have two sons, each with his own laptop.  Each of them has a Steam account.

Now when one buys a game, is it possible for the other one to download it too (without paying again)?

I have tried what they refer to as 'Family Library Sharing' but it seems to be for several accounts on the **same** computer.
I've also tried adding a computer to *Manage other computers* but can't find how to do that either.

I would imagine this is a straightforward issue but can't work it out...

What's the deal?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 7):

You were on the right track.

Simply login to all your accounts on each machine and enable Family Sharing for them.

This way everyone will be able to play (almost) any game as long as the owner isn't actively playing anything (on Steam).

E.g. any of your sons may play any of your games as long as you're not playing anything.

Comment: And as long as the other son isn't also playing something from your library.  Only one game from any given library can be played at a time.

Comment: Family sharing is the way to go. Just to elaborate for the OP about logging in: Me and my girlfriend are family sharing our accounts. She's logged in on her machine (and has access to my games via the "Flater's games" category in her library), I'm logged in on my machine (and have access to her games via the "[name]'s Games" category in my library). It's possible that we needed to log in on eachother's machines initially to set it up, I don't quite remember. But since it's been set up, we are both on our own account and don't need to use each other's account details to play our games.

Comment: @Flater you need to initially log into the computer that will be shared to (playing the games) to be able to authorize it

Comment: But keep in mind that you can get punished if the account you granted Family Sharing right cheats or violates the terms of service in some way.